# JAVA Boolean constructor gives unexpected result

Tags: java, constructor, boolean

I just wrote a code:

```
Boolean b1 = new Boolean("programmer");
Boolean b2 = new Boolean("tester");
System.out.println(b1.equals(b2));
```

It prints `true` as ouput. **Why?**

> **According to JAVA documentation**
>
> `new Boolean(String)`: Allocates a Boolean object representing the value true if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring
>   case, to the string "true".

Comment: Both Booleans are false, therefor they are equal and your equals check will print out true. Nothing really unexpected here.

Comment: Read your last sentence very carefully. It gives you the reason.

Comment: Because "Allocates a Boolean object representing the value true if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true"."  Anything else is false.

Comment: I didn't understood the cause of downvotes..

Comment: You can consider this kind of constructor a design mistake. Well, generally, all constructors of `Boolean` are a design mistake as the possibility to create distinct `Boolean` instances makes no sense, but this specific semantic, similar to `Boolean.valueOf(String)`, converting arbitrary strings or even `null` to `false`, is another design flaw. Still, when two `Boolean` objects are not equal, one of them must represent `true`. Which one would you expect to be `true`? None? Then, both objects must be equal…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Boolean b1 = new Boolean("programmer"); // false
Boolean b2 = new Boolean("tester"); // false
```

So testing `false == false` is `true`.

---

> **From *[`public Boolean(String s)` constructor signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#Boolean(java.lang.String))*:**
>
> - `Boolean.parseBoolean("True")` returns `true`
> - `Boolean.parseBoolean("yes")` returns `false`

Answer (score 3):

Both your `b1` and `b2` are `Boolean.FALSE`, therefore they're equal.

Only if the String is `"true"` (ignoring case) will `new Boolean(String)` be `TRUE`.

Here's the constructor for `Boolean`:

```
   public Boolean(String s) {
        this(parseBoolean(s));
    }
```

And the `parseBoolean` method:

```
public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) {
    return ((s != null) && s.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Default value of boolean is false.. and in your case

```
Boolean b1 = new Boolean("programmer"); // false
System.out.println(b1);
Boolean b2 = new Boolean("tester"); // false
System.out.println(b2);
```

So `false == false` always return `true`

In addition to that, If you want to compare the strings that you have given, then you should use **`String`** wrapper class.